# Can't get CSS to load in web app

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, servlets

Hi I am totally unable to get my CSS to load.  I've tried every combination of adding and removing slashes, using getContextPath(), and moved the CSS to every folder I can think of.  Would really appreciate any help.  Thanks.
[Here's my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v0YW.png)

The JSP in question

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashboard</title>

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "/css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body class="background">
</body>
</html>
```

My web.xml

```
<!-- webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml -->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>To do List</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.do</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

     <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <filter>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
       </filter>

       <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
       </filter-mapping> 


</web-app>
```

My controller

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)    
    public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model){
        return "home";
    }

}
```

And my servlet configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.angels" />

        <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
         <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

    </beans>
```

Comment: When starting out I heavily suggest you use SpringBoot. I know there are some old tutorials around on the internet (I myself learnt Spring from outdated xml config type tutorials), it is just too easy to make mistakes. Otherwise you spend all your time on configuration which is a waste.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it.  The tutorials that I have been learning from have provided ready-to-go configuration files so I haven't been prepared to a) recreate or b) extend functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.In your spring config xml file, add the below

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

2.Place your CSS files under **webapp/resources/css/styles.css**

3.Refer CSS in your JSP

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/styles.css"/>
```